# How can I treat different canvas-drawing as one , and how can I trace the sequence among them?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a scenario in which I am having a canvas, I am dragging some drawing from the left side of the canvas and dropping it on the right side of it and if I am dropping one box near to another one it also clubbing together. Now I need to do two more things -

1. First, as soon as I am clubbing one with another I want to give this set, of more than one boxes, a treatment of one box. meaning that if I am dragging any one of the box which are clubbed together, whole set of the boxes should be dragged together.
2. second, as and when I am dropping the boxes I want to generate some plain text based on the box which has been dropped, for example if I dropped "first box", the plain text should be something like "you dropped first box first". And this thing I need to do on the sequence, meaning if the second box is appearing first the text according to that box should appear first.

Here is the code which I have completed

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
                draw();
            }
        </script>
    <body style="margin: 0;padding:0;clear:both; cursor: pointer">
        <canvas id="canvas" tabindex="1" style="float:left" ></canvas>
        <div id="plainEnglish" tabindex="2" style="float: left;"></div>
    </body>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

c.width = 600;
c.height = 300;

//My mouse coordinates
var x,y;
c.addEventListener("mousedown",down);
c.addEventListener("mousemove",move);
c.addEventListener("mouseup",up);

var r = 0;

function counter() {
 r++;
 console.log(r);
}

//I'll save my boxes in this array
var myBoxes = new Array();

// Those boxes which I have moved to droppable area of the canvas.
var myDroppedBoxes = new Array();

//This function describes what a box is.
//Each created box gets its own values
function box(x,y,w,h,rgb,text) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y;
    this.xS = x; //saving x
    this.yS = y; //saving y
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.rgb = rgb;
    this.text = text;

    //to determine if the box is being draged
    this.draging = false;
    this.isBeingDragged = false;
}

//Let's make some boxes!!
myBoxes[0] = new box(20,20,75,20,"#6AA121","First");
myBoxes[1] = new box(20,50,75,20,"#6AA121", "Second");
myBoxes[2] = new box(20,80,75,20,"#6AA121","third");

//here we draw everything
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    //Dropable area
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.fillRect(c.width/2,0,c.width,c.height);

    //Boxes!
    for (var i = 0; i<myBoxes.length; i++) {
        var b = myBoxes[i];
        if (b.draging) { //box on the move
            //Also draw it on the original spot
            ctx.fillStyle=b.rgb; 
            ctx.fillRect(b.xS,b.yS,b.w,b.h);
            ctx.strokeRect(b.xS,b.yS,b.w,b.h);
            ctx.font = "14px Arial";
            ctx.strokeText(b.text, b.xS + 5 , b.yS + 15);
        }

        ctx.fillStyle=b.rgb;
        ctx.fillRect(b.x,b.y,b.w,b.h);
        ctx.strokeRect(b.x,b.y,b.w,b.h);
        ctx.font = "14px Arial";
        ctx.strokeText(b.text, b.x + 5 , b.y + 15);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i< myDroppedBoxes.length; i++) {
        var b = myDroppedBoxes[i];
        ctx.fillStyle=b.rgb;
        ctx.fillRect(b.x,b.y,b.w,b.h);
        ctx.strokeRect(b.x,b.y,b.w,b.h);
        ctx.font = "14px Arial";
        ctx.strokeText(b.text, b.x + 5 , b.y + 15);
    }


}


function down(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    x = event.pageX - c.offsetLeft,
    y = event.pageY - c.offsetTop;

    for (var i = 0; i<myBoxes.length; i++) {
        var b = myBoxes[i];
        if (x>b.xS && x<b.xS+b.w && y>b.yS && y<b.yS+b.h) {
            myBoxes[i].draging = true;
            myBoxes[i].isBeingDragged = true;
        }

    }

    for (var i = 0; i<myDroppedBoxes.length; i++) {
        var b = myDroppedBoxes[i];
        if (x>b.x && x<b.x + b.w && y>b.y && y<b.y + b.h) {
            b.draging = true;
            b.isBeingDragged = true;
        }

    }
    draw();
}

function move(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    x = event.pageX - c.offsetLeft,
    y = event.pageY - c.offsetTop;

    for (var i = 0; i<myBoxes.length; i++) {
        var b = myBoxes[i];
        if (b.draging && b.isBeingDragged) {
            myBoxes[i].x = x;
            myBoxes[i].y = y;

            if (b.x>c.width/2) {
            var length = myDroppedBoxes.length ;
                myDroppedBoxes[length] = new box(x,y,b.w,b.h,b.rgb,b.text);
                myDroppedBoxes[length].draging = true;
                myDroppedBoxes[length].isBeingDragged = true;
                b.x = b.xS;
                b.y = b.yS;
                b.isBeingDragged = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i<myDroppedBoxes.length; i++) {
        var b = myDroppedBoxes[i];
        if (b.draging && b.isBeingDragged) {
            b.x = x;
            b.y = y;
        }
    }
    draw();
}
function up(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    x = event.pageX - c.offsetLeft,
    y = event.pageY - c.offsetTop;

    for (var i = 0; i< myBoxes.length; i++) {
        var b = myBoxes[i];
        if (b.draging && b.isBeingDragged) {
            //Let's see if the rectangle is inside the dropable area
            if (b.x < c.width/2) {
                myBoxes[i].x = b.xS;
                myBoxes[i].y = b.yS;
                myBoxes[i].draging = false;
                b.isBeingDragged = false;
            }

        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i< myDroppedBoxes.length; i++) {
        var b = myDroppedBoxes[i];
        if ( b.isBeingDragged) {
            //Let's see if the rectangle is inside the dropable area
            if (b.x>c.width/2) {
                b.x = x;
                b.y = y;
                clubLegos(b);
                plainTextMaker();
                b.isBeingDragged = false;
            }
            else {
                //No it's not, sending it back to its original spot   
               myDroppedBoxes.splice(i,1);
            }

        }

    }
    draw();
}

function clubLegos(b) {
    // this loop is for checking that the box is lying near to which other box.
    for(var j = 0; j < myDroppedBoxes.length; j++) {  
        var z =  myDroppedBoxes[j];
        if(!z.isBeingDragged) {
                if(((x > z.x) && (x < (z.x + z.w))) && ((y > (z.y - 15)) && (y < (z.y + z.h + 10)))) {
                    b.x = z.x;
                    if( (y - z.y) >= 0) {
                        b.y = (z.y + z.h);
                        console.log("inside if " + y + " " + z.y);
                    }
                    else {
                    console.log("inside else " +  y + " " + z.y);
                        b.y = (z.y - z.h);
                    }


                }
        }
    }
}

function plainTextMaker() {
    plainEnglishDiv =  document.getElementById("plainEnglish");
    plainEnglishDiv.innerHTML = "<h3>Here I am generating some plain text based on each drag and drop</h3>";
}

</script>
</html>
```

Here is the JS Fiddle for the same - 
http://jsfiddle.net/akki166786/wa52f9pm/

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Give each of your box objects something similar to Html's `class`.**

This way you can drag every box with the same "class" simultaneously.

Add a `club:` property to each box.

```
// at top of app set a counter to make new clubs
var nextClub=0;

// each new box gets a unique "club"
function box(x,y,w,h,rgb,text) {
    ...
    club:(nextClub++),
    ...
```

In `clubLegos(b)` when you're attaching dragged box `b` to another box `z`, also give the dropped box (b) & any member of (z)'s group a brand new club id:

```
// give the dropped box (b) & any member of (z)'s group a brand new club id
...if attaching b to z
b.club=nextClub;
for(var i=0;i<myBoxes.length;i++){
    var bb=myBoxes[i];
    if(bb.club==z.club){
        bb.club=nextClub;
    }
}
nextClub++;
```

This way, for example, if the mousedown has the user starting to drag a box with `club==2`, then you can add each `myBoxes` with `club==2` into your dragging array and every box with `club==2` will be dragged simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but now I am thinking to do it on the basis of pixels,it goes like if have to check if any other box's pixels are attached to the box then make it move with the above one, because I want another thing that if I lift a box all box below this should move along but not the boxes above the box upon which I clicked, does that make sense?

Comment: Pixel hit testing is expensive and is usually reserved for testing irregular shapes. Since you are hit testing known-sized rectangles the mathematical hit tests are just as accurate as pixel tests. So expensive pixel testing is not needed here. ;-) As to lifting the dragged lego and only connected leggos above that lego...sure, in `mousedown` just examine all legos in the dragged lego's `club` and create a new club for those legos with `y<=draggedLeggo.y`. Then drag that new club and leave the previously connected legos in their previous club. Good luck with your project! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information and wishes, I got what you are saying here but actually my next plan is to change the shape from rectangular to something irregular(exactly looking like lego), so for that should i go with pixels based approach or club based approach? I am not able to foresee the challenges ahead.